# Does C++ call the destructor when an object goes out of scope?

Tags: c++, scope, stack, destructor

I thought yes, but

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    int t;
};

class C {
private:
    S s;
public:
    C() {s.t = 7;}
    ~C(){std::cout << "bye C" << std::endl;}
};

class D {
private:
    S s;
public:
    D(int t) {s.t = t;}
    ~D() {std::cout << "bye D(" << s.t << ")" << std::endl;}
};

int main() {
    C c0();
    C* c1 = new C();
    D d0();
    D d1(42);
    std::cout << __LINE__ << std::endl;
    delete c1;
    std::cout << __LINE__ << std::endl;
}
```

just prints (https://ideone.com/95DK9E)

```
28
bye C
30
bye D(42)
```

So why are `c0` and `d0` not properly destructed by a call to their destructor?

Comment: `c0` and `d0` are not objects, but functions returning objects.

Comment: Change the function declarations to `C c0{};` and `D d0{};`, or to `C c0;` and `D d0;` so they become local variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c0` and `d0` are not objects. You've written two function declarations.

Comment: Never forget https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse